# Send R code from Visual Studio Code to R session outside of VS Code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

Question:
How do I send code from Visual Studio Code to a pre-existing R.exe session that I opened before I launched Visual Studio Code?

Background:
I just switched from Sublime to Visual Studio Code and I miss the functionality of being able to send code from my text editor to an active R session. I can send code successfully to a terminal inside of Visual Studio Code using the R extension for Visual Studio Code but this is not what I want to do. Sometimes it is beneficial to view graphics natively in R rather than inside Visual Studio Code or be able to share just one "screen" when presenting to a virtual audience.

System:
Windows
Visual Studio Code 1.62.3
R extension for Visual Studio Code 2.3.4
R 4.1.2

Thank you for entertaining my question and please do let me know how I can make it better or if I should of posted it somewhere else.

Comment: To clarify, you already have open R.exe on your computer, and then you want to open up VSCode as a script editor, and you want VSCode to send that code to the R.exe console running outside of VSCode instead of sending it to an R terminal running inside VSCode? If so, may I ask why not just use the R terminal in VSCode from the get-go?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want to do. I have updated my original post with two examples of why. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I don't think the VSCode R extension currently supports that. You can change your external terminal to R in your JSON settings `"terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.2\\bin\\R.exe"` and tell VSCode to launch it with `Ctrl+Shift+C`, but I can't see how to send R commands from its internal script editor to the external R terminal. Being able to separate the terminal from VSCode is a top-requested feature on GitHub, so perhaps they'll add it in soon: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10121

Comment: In the meantime, you can always create your R scripts in VSCode, save them, and then when presenting virtually, launch the R console and just use its built-in script editor via `File > Open script...` (make sure `Edit > Gui Preferences` has `SDI` selected under "Single or Multiple" and `multiple windows` selected under "Pager Style". That way you can have them on separate screens and get your native R graphics. Alternatively, you could re-size VSCode so that it spans multiple monitors and then reposition the terminal vertically or horizontally to separate it from the editor across monitors.

Comment: By the way, you can have the R terminal in VSCode pop out plots in 'native R'. If you're currently using the `httpgd` package to view them internally, you can turn it off in your JSON settings: `"r.plot.useHttpgd": false"`. You can also navigate to the plot pane and press the button to display the plot in an external browser. Or, if you just want it to be a one-off in native R, you can preface your plot command with `windows()`, like this: `windows(); plot(mtcars$mpg)`.

Comment: Is there any way to do this now? I'm looking for a way to send code from VS Code to R.app, just as it was possible to do in Atom