# How to send code from VS Code to separate R app?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, vscodium

I've just switched from Atom to VS Code and I am looking for a way to send code from VSC to the native R.app terminal, outside of VS Code. Same way as it could be done with Atom. But so far I could only use the R Terminal *within* VS Code.

I saw [old questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70371160/send-r-code-from-visual-studio-code-to-r-session-outside-of-vs-code) asking this, and that using separate terminals was [already asked in vscode repository](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10121) (and the issue has been closed), but I still can't find how to do it.

I am using macOS Ventura, R 4.3, and VSCodium 1.85.